# Automate Excel in VC++

Tags: c++, excel, visual-c++, automation

I was working on a MFC project in VS2008 which requires a feature of reading Excel. I have been trying to make it by following the [instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-excel-from-mfc-fill-data) in MS Docs. However, after adding those classes and compiling the project, I got many many errors in a **excel.tlh** file, such as

```
C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C3203: _com_IIID unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter '_IIID', expected a real type
C2504: '_IMsoDispObj'； base class undefined
```

There are more errors, but I am going to paste it here to avoid verbosity. Any suggestion for how this happened and how to **solve** it?

Comment: Try XInt library, it's an open source c++project for reading/writing in xlsx format, works well with VC++.

Comment: I tried Xlnt by following [instructions](http://settleques.com/index.php/2019/06/09/how-to-compile-the-xlnt-by-cmake-and-deploy-it-to-visual-studio-2017-in-windows/) in Visual Studio 2015. I could xlnt.dll, xlnt.lib, but when adding those files to the project, there are 1000+ errors. Do you know why that happens and how to fix them?

Comment: You can use vcpkg to auto install it for you or you can manually link the .dll and .lib files to your project.

Comment: I don't know those skills, could you explain it in detail or give me a some links?

Comment: Actually I find the previous compilation succeed because I didn't build all projects. When I selected all projects and build, I ended up with 10 errors MSB307: `The command "setlocal
"D:\Program Files\CMake\bin\ctest.exe" --force-new-ctest-process -C Debug
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
:VCEnd" exited with code 8.` Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: You can download vcpkg from GitHub, will be useful for your future projects, and now you are one line away before installing your project.